# Is mysql_install_db needed to install MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, vps, mariadb

I'm learning to run my own VPS and I tried install whole stack few times already. But I found one thing that is not same in the all tutorials: `mysql_install_db` command.

I'm using Ubuntu LTS and it was always like this:

```
apt install mariadb-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

Everything running. Now I found that after install there should be iniciallization command. I'm confused, because all seems running fine, but maybe my installation is missing something important? Or this `mysql_install_db` command is not needed at all? Will be thankful for the explanation.

Comment: Consider using Docker; it may take care of more details.

Answer (score 2):

The [`mysql_secure_installation`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_secure_installation/) is a security script, whereas [`mysql_install_db`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_install_db/)

> initializes the MariaDB data directory and creates the system tables in
>   the mysql database, if they do not exist.

Because you have installed MariaDB as a package from your distribution using `apt install mariadb-server` this initialization has been already done. Therefore, you don't need to run the script `mysql_install_db`, but you still benefit from running `mysql_secure_installation`.